# Using a contour integral about a branch cut to compute $\int \limits ^\infty _0 \frac {\ln x} {x^a (x+1)} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Find the value of $I = \int \limits ^\infty _0 \frac {\ln x} {x^a (x+1)} dx$ for $a \in (0,1)$, placing the branch cut of the logarithm on the positive real axis.

You can use the result that $\int \limits ^\infty _0 \frac 1 {x^a (x+1)} dx = \frac \pi {\sin(\pi a)}$.

Using a keyhole contour to skirt around the branch cut we can determine that the value of the closed integral $\oint\frac {\ln z} {z^a (z+1)} dz$ excluding the real axis is $ 2\pi i \cdot \text{Res(f,-1)} = -2\pi^2 e^{-\pi i a}$ due to the pole at $ z = -1$.

Using this information, I need to find the value of the integral along the real line.

The next step in the question should be to split the contour integral into separate parts and evaluate them individually to deduce the value of the part on the real axis but I haven't have any success in doing so.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: In the first line?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Second and third line is the beginning of your solution?

Comment: I've added some more, is it clearer now?

Comment: You don't have to perform any integration: Notice that
$\partial_a x^{-a}=-\log(x)x^{-a}$ so you  just have to differentiate your given integral w.r.t $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $f(a)$ be the integral defined by

$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^a(1+x)}\,dx$$

We evaluate $f(a)$ by analyzing the contour integral

$$I=\oint_C\frac{\log(z)}{z^a(1+z)}\,dz$$

where $C$ is the classical keyhole contour integral.  We can write

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^a(1+x)}\,dx+\int_\infty^0\frac{\log(x)+i2\pi}{e^{i2\pi a}\,x^a(1+x)}=2\pi i\text{Res}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z^a(1+z)},z=-1\right) \tag 1$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT**

> From $(1)$, we can write $$\begin{align}(1-e^{-i2\pi a})\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^a(1+x)}&=2\pi i\left(e^{-i2\pi a}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^a(1+x)}\,dx+\text{Res}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z^a(1+z)},z=-1\right)\right)\\\\\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^a(1+x)}&=\frac{\pi e^{i\pi a}}{\sin(\pi a)}\left(\frac{\pi e^{-i2\pi a}}{\sin(\pi a)}+\frac{i\pi}{e^{i\pi a}}\right)\\\\&=\pi^2\cot(\pi a)\csc(\pi a)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I realised that I had to consider the 2i pi for the logarithm but I was neglecting the multiplier for x^a. How would I derive that e^(2pi i a) factor?

Comment: On the upper-part of the keyhole, the argument of $z$ is $0$ so $z^a=x^a$ and $\log(z)=\log(x)$.  On the lower-part of the keyhole, the argument of $z$ is $2\pi$ so $z^a=x^ae^{i2\pi a}$ and $\log(z) = \log(x)+i2\pi.$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome David.  My pleasure!  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm so sorry to bring this up again, but there's something I don't understand. Can you please  elaborate on the reason for the $e^{i2 \pi} a$ factor? I had the idea, that since the in the denominator (as you mentioned) we have $z^a = x^a e^{i2 \pi a}$, then the factor should be $e^{- i2 \pi a}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @UriaMor Uria, thank you for catching the typographical error.  I have corrected it now. And +1 for your comment.  Nice catch.  -Mark

Comment: I was so afraid that I'm missing something I actually spent an hour validating before asking. Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: @UriaMor You're welcome.  My pleasure!  -Mark